# Variable in URL in PHP Echo

Tags: php, variables

I need some help..

I have a line of PHP that is echoing a url for me -

```
<?php foreach($day as $item) : ?>
        <li style="background: url('<?php echo http://$base:$sickport/api/$SICKAPI/?cmd=show.getbanner&tvdbid=$item['tvdbid']?>')"><?php echo $item['show_name'] ?> </br> <?php echo $item['ep_name'] ?></li>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

The problem I have is that the URL here -

```
<li style="background: url('<?php echo http://$base:$sickport/api/$SICKAPI/?cmd=show.getbanner&tvdbid=$item['tvdbid']?>')">
```

Appears to kill the code, so I assume my syntax is wrong, if I remove the "background stuff" the code works and the other 2 variables are mapped ok, i'm now wanting to set the backgroud of each li as per the image being returned from the API call, but I can't get it working..i'm sure someone here will sort it really easily for me..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you have syntax error in your code:

**Modified Example:**

```
<li style='background: url(<?php echo 'http://$base:$sickport/api/$SICKAPI/?cmd=show.getbanner&tvdbid='.$item['tvdbid'];?>)'>
```

**Alternate Solution:**

```
<?php
$url = "http://$base:$sickport/api/$SICKAPI/?cmd=show.getbanner&tvdbid=".$item['tvdbid'];
?>

<li style='background: url(<?php echo $url; ?>)'>
```

Comment: Ok, Your first modified example works for my "item" but my other variables now don't work so the output is -     <li style='background: url("http://$base:$sickport/api/$SICKAPI/?cmd=show.getbanner&tvdbid=78419)'>
Sesame Street </br> Say Thank You to Your Face Day</li>

Comment: And your alternate solution (I like more) works for the other variables, but doesn't seem to resolve the .item['tvdbid'] variable?

Comment: @user3768497: fix small typo. try now

Comment: @user3768497: glad to help